# Time complexity of Map.clear in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, time-complexity, scala-collections

When called on a `Map`, is the time complexity of `clear` O(1) or O(n) on the size of the map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of immutable maps don't have clear since they are immutable but they do have empty which returns a new empty map of that type. Since it is just an object creation it is O(1). Mutable maps however are O(n) where n is based on the underlying data structure since they have to clear out that data structure. For the typical mutable HashMap this will be a table. The table size will be between 0.75 and 1.5 the maximum size the Map has been in the past.

Comment: Technically, it is O(n) for n size of the table, not for n number of elements.

Comment: True. But O(n) by table size or by map size is equivalent when, by default, the size of the table is kept at some power of 2 that is just greater than 0.75 * the map size. This means that the O(n) of the table is between O( 0.75 * m ) and O( 1.5 * m ) of the map size m. And in O notation constants factor out as O(1) so O(n) == O(m)

Comment: You assume that no elements were ever deleted. The table might well be _empty_, and it would still take O(n), for whatever size n the table has reached.

Comment: I've modified the answer accordingly. Thank you Daniel.